# TeamCity service message block error in build log

Tags: .net, teamcity

I use the following code in my NUnit to write to TeamCity's build log.

```
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[blockOpened name='ARRANGE']")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[testStep name='Step 1 : Arrange Export Manager'")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[testStep name='Step 2 : Arrange the object to be exported'")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[testStep name='Step 3 : Export the object to be exported'")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[testStep name='Step 4 : Assert that export worked'")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[testStep name='Step 5 : Arrange Import Manager'")
Console.WriteLine("##teamcity[blockClosed name='ARRANGE']")
```

and it produces the following in the build log:
[image]

any idea why there is **[Test Error Output]** message after the block name ?